# How do I check if a string is a float number or an integer number?

Tags: python, numeric

`"1.0".isnumeric()` -> False

I need to know if that string is actually a float number or an integer number because there although the string is in fact a float number the .`isnumeric()` returns `False`

Comment: Your options are probably either: (a) test with a suitable regex, or (b) call `float` and catch any `ValueError` exception. Very likely this question has been asked before if you search some more.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is convert the string into its actual datatype using `ast.literal_eval` method and then use the `isinstance` method to check if it is a float number or not.

```
>>> import ast
>>> string = '1.0'
>>>
>>> num = ast.literal_eval(string)
>>> num
1.0
>>> isinstance(num,float)
True
>>>
```

Same way you can check if it is an integer. Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
def is_numeric(some_string):
    try:
        float(some_string)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(is_numeric("123"))
    print(is_numeric("1.0"))
    print(is_numeric("1.0asd"))
```

Output:

```
True
True
False
```